# Pass string data from activity to non-activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, textview

I am trying to pass string data from activity to non-activity, not the other way around. I have some code but it does not work and throws this error `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:` and I believe because the second class is not activity so it does not have constructor. 
here is my code:

This is in my MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("message", value);
    startActivity(intent);
```

And this is in my SecondActivity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String value = bundle.getString("message");
```

Comment: Post your `SecondActivity` code

Comment: Create constructor with `String` param

Comment: @dieter_h  How can I do that?

Comment: You're treating your non-activity as an `Activity`...stop

Comment: Post `SecondActivity` code.

Comment: @codeMagic So how should I change that?

Comment: By not using an `Intent`. [Read about passing arguments around](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Programming 101 `Classes and how they work`

A basic class

```
public class MyClass{

    private String myString;

    //default constructor with no parameters
    public MyClass(){}

    //Constructor that takes parameters
    public MyClass(String value){
        myString = value;
    }

    //get the string
    public String getMyString(){
        return myString
    }

}
```

`Using the class`

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(yourString);
.
.
.
.
String whatsMyString = myClass.getMyString()
```